# Visual C# how to make it so people using my program dont have to install the MySql Frame work

Tags: c#, mysql, database, dll

so I am making a program the inserts info into a MySQL database but right now everyone haves to install the MySQL frame work I was wondering if there was a way I could but the .dll file in the program resources

Answer (score 0):

You can download the MySQL noinstall which comes with a DLL
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=393501

Right click your Project > Add Reference > Browse and select the DLL's which you need from the MySQL zip

Comment: I have the dll but how do I add it to my project

Comment: wait it still requires them to have it on there desktop

Comment: Requires them to have what on there desktop ?? If you mean the DDL then you have 2 options from my experience. 
1: Store the DDL in GAC see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx
2.Store the EXE and DDL together in program files and create a short-cut to your EXE on the desktop